# Capture with negative look behind

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Let's assume I have the following subject:

```
abcdef ghidef
```

and I want to match **word ending with def not preceeded by abc** (in this case it would be ghidef). How can I match this?

When I use:

```
(?<!abc)def
```

I'm getting the 2nd `def` but I'm not getting `ghi` here.

Comment: [*"An assertion is a test on the characters following or preceding the current matching point that **does not actually consume any characters.**"*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Comment: Your question is very unclear: you should have stated you need to match words that do not start with `abc`  and that end with `def`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of lookbehind. You can use with a negative lookahead:

```
\b(?!abc)\w*def\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sz3GId/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b` - assert a word boundary
- `(?!abc)` - is negative lookahead that asserts a word doesn't start with `abc` after `\b` (word boundary)
- `\w*` - match 0 or more word characters
- `def` - ending text of word is `def`
- `\b` - word boundary

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I've tried to achieve :)